# resourceId not being reset after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

So for my select function within fullcalendar, I'm using it to add appointments to the calendar. On the first appointment that I add to the calendar, the resourceId variable is correct, and the appointment gets added in the correct position. From there on out, any time i add an appointment, it gets added under that resource, the variable never changes to the resourceId to the slot I clicked on in my calendar.

```
select: function(start, end, event, view, resource) {
    $("#addEventModal").modal('show');
    $("#addAppt").submit(function(e) {
      $("#apptSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      console.log(resource.id);
      var formData = $(this).serialize() + '&start=' + moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') +
      '&end=' + moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') + '&resourceId=' + resource.id;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/dentist/db/createAppt.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(){
          $('#addEventModal').modal('hide');
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          $("#apptSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
        },
      });
    });
  },
```

I'm really not sure what's causing this, because my understanding is that anytime the submit button of my modal is clicked (#addAppt), the resourceId will be set to the id of whichever slot was clicked on. If anyone knows what's causing this it would be much appreciated.

This is the html for my modal

```
<div id="addEventModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up For Appointment</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="addAppt" class='form-signin'>
        <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name = "firstName" id="inputFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name = "lastName" id="inputLastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        <button id="apptSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: in `$("apptSubmit")`  apptSubmit is a custom dom element?

Comment: why are you using ids?where is your html?

Comment: $("apptSubmit") is the submit button on the form within my modal

Comment: then you forgot the # from the id

Comment: Woops, well i fixed those silly mistakes I made but i still get the same behavior that i stated from the original question